# UIView addSubview works once but not twice

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to add a `UIButton` in a `UIView` from my xib file.

In my xib, I declare a `UIView` outlet named "content" with interface builder: here is the generated code :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *content;
```

I would like to add a button, here is the code for this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 8, 141.0, 56.0);
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TAB_NORMAL"] 
                                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 8, 56.0, 141.0);
[self.content addSubview:button];
```

If I put this code in `-viewDidLoad` method, it works, but if I put it in a function called later, the button is never displayed.

What could be the reason ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: From where do you call the other method?

Comment: Are you changing anything in the code? Otherwise you're just adding it at the same position.

Comment: I call this method from the viewcontroller itself which is a singleton. I change nothing, I only add this button which is the first subview in content

Comment: this is a prime time to learn the debugger (if you haven't already). set a break point where it is being added and see what's going on. Is content non-nil? what are the subviews of content before and after the call? Is it actually being called like you think?

Comment: also, why are you setting the frame twice?

Comment: I'm surprised, the content view is nil when I want to add the button. Before the call, there is a UIImageView which is still displayed when the call is done

Answer (score 1):

If your UIView `content` is a top level item, that is, not contained in your main view - then it has to be `strong`. Only items that are not top-level can use `weak`, since the containing view would keep a strong reference to them. I also assume that `content` was immediately added to the primary view, which kept a strong reference to it (it in viewDidLoad happened before ARC nil'ed out `content`.

If for some reason changing the property to `strong` does not fix the problem, then for sure add a NSLog (or assert) to insure that `content` is non-nil.

Comment: I have changed @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *content;

Comment: To strong? What happened? If its not fixed, what do the logs say?

Comment: with nslog I can see that content is nil

Comment: Your not helping me by not answering questions - so right now I have no idea what your code looks like. So lets try again with one new change. 1) confirm that the property is strong. 2) in `viewDidLoad`, log "content" to confirm its originally not nil (meaning, the outlet is not set in IB). 3) That later, after never nil'ing content yourself, that its now nil.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 1) I confirm that content property is strong. 2) in viewDidLoad content is not nil. 3) I never nil it myself and it is nil. I can see in my nslog debug that the log for my custom method is displayed before the log for the viewdidload method ... This means that my content is used before its initialisation, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes! So that is your problem! Set a flag or something so you don't call your customer method til viewDidLoad occurs.